# How do I change a controls background on my UserControl when the item is selected

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I have this ListView which has a DataTemplate of my UserContol because I wanted a custom design for my ListView and it looks like this

```
<ListView x:Name="LeftMenuListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem}"
          BorderThickness="0"
          Width="255">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <local:MenuItemControl/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Super simple, now when an Item is selected the entire thing changes color
which I want it looks great imo

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border
                        Name="Border"
                        BorderThickness="0">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                                    Value="#444444"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But there is a border inside my usercontrol thats 10px wide with the name SmallBorder.
I want to change the color of that to green when the item is selected but I have no idea how to access that property

My UserControl

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="20,0,0,0"
               Foreground="#9e9e9e"
               FontFamily="Tahoma"/>

    <Border Width="10"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            x:Name="SmallBorder"/>
</Grid>
```

So how do I change the color of `SmallBorder` when an item is selected and then when it's not selected it turns transparent?

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModel, which is the DataContext of you usercontrol, should expose a property like IsSelected, then you can add an style with a DataTrigger that reacts to a change in this property.

**EDIT:**

Declare an style for the border itself an access it as an StaticResource: 
It could be placed in a ResourceDictionary,  within YourUserControl.Resources or inline with the Border control declaration:

```
<Style TargetType={x:Type Border} x:Key=SelectedBorderStyle>
    <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
       </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And then your UserControl would be:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="20,0,0,0"
               Foreground="#9e9e9e"
               FontFamily="Tahoma"/>

    <Border Width="10"
            Style={StaticResource SelectedBorderStyle}
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
```

Note that now you don't need to set the name for the Border.

Comment: `TargetName="SmallBorder"` is not recognized though, why is that?

Comment: Makes sense, I wrote it like if it was a ControlTemplate, what you need to do is to create and style for the border itself, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

A `Border` is invisible unless there is something in it, but you could replace the `Border` with a `Grid` and use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to the `IsSelected` property:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="20,0,0,0"
               Foreground="#9e9e9e"
               FontFamily="Tahoma"/>

    <Grid Width="10"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          x:Name="SmallBorder">
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```